# How to mock HttpConfiguration?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have to test the controller in my unit tests. This controller requires "HttpConfiguration" in the constructor. I would like to use Moq to imitate an object, but I don't know how to do it." HttpConfiguration "has neither interface nor virtual methods.

The tested method contains such a call
`Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions`

What can I do to set "ApiDescriptions" in mock?

Answer (score 0):

HttpConfiguration doesn't implement any interface and since you can't mock real implementation of the class with Moq, you might want to create a custom wrapper around it, let's say like this:

```
public interface IHttpConfiguration
{
     bool IsPositive(int num);
}
```

And then make your `HttpConfiguration` class implement it:

```
public class HttpConfiguration: IHttpConfiguration
{
     public bool IsPositive(int num)
     {
        return num > 0;
     }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
     private readonly IHttpConfiguration _httpConfiguration;

     public MyController(IHttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
     {
        _httpConfiguration = httpConfiguration;
     }

     //Your controller methods here
}
```

Assuming you're using .NET Core, in your Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IHttpConfiguration, HttpConfiguration>();
        //other logic here
    }
}
```

In your unit test class:

```
public class MyControllerTest
{
    private Mock<IHttpConfiguration> _mockHttpConfiguration;
    private MyController _myController;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _mockHttpConfiguration = new Mock<IHttpConfiguration>();
        _myController = new MyController(_mockHttpConfiguration.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMock()
    {
        //mock methods you need and assert
        _mockHttpConfiguration.Setup(x=>x.IsPositive(2)).Returns(false); 
    }
}
```

I used `IsPositive()` for demonstration purposes only. You have to apply the same logic for methods in HttpConfiguration class that you want to mock.